# Xcode - Custom Class with a subproject

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I have a project A within another project B. In the Project A I have the "core" of my program and in the Project B I do the customize things. I created also some empty custom class in Project A, so that I can ovverride them in the Project B.

For example... In Project A I have the class Square.h with all methods and an empty SquareCustom.h which is a subclass of Square. Then I have a class Shapes.h which include SquareCustom.

In the Project B I import Square.h and Shapes.h, but I write a new SquareCustom.h with my custom methods. I do this because I can keep the same Shape.h that point to SquareCustom.h whetever the project is.

My problem now is that when I work on SquareCustom.xib on Project B Xcode get a bit messy. SquareCustom.xib file owners is the correct SquareCustom from Project B when I compile, but in the Interface Builder if I press the arrow near the "Custom class" in the Identity Inspector it points to the wrong one (the whole one from Project A). This is really annoying because I always have to choose it manually when I work with the assistant editor.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly you have 2 `SquareCustom` classes, one in project A and an other in project B ?

This is a class name collision, and should be avoided like hell. This is the reason why [Apple recommends prefixing class names with uppercase letters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html). You should not be trying to create one on purpose.

This is your problem. What is the point of having `SquareCustom` in project A anyway, considering that it is empty ?

The logical way to do it for me would be to have `Square` in project A and then create `CustomSquare` in project B as a subclass of `Square` (from project A). This seems to be a clean design (project A which acts as an extern library does not know about its consumers, you don't duplicate class names), it achieves what I understand you wanna do. And IB would get less confused about which `CustomSquare` to use considering that there would be only one now.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but how do I keep an unique "Shape.h" that point to "Square.h" in my main project and "SquareCustom.h" for the custom one?

I did this trick for keeping a placeholder that let me have an unique "Shape.h" for both files.

Comment: Well, you would not be able to do that in project A, as you guess. Why do you need `Shape.h` to be in project A ? Or why do you need `Shape.h` in the first place ? If you did what I suggest, you could just `#import "SquareCustom.h"` and it would include both `SquareCustom`and `Square` (which is the superclass).

Comment: Shape.h is an example. I have tons of class that needs to import "SquareCustom.h" but I can't rewrite each of these classed for everyproject, so I'd like to write in them #import "SquareCustom.h" and then implement SquareCustom in every project. Shape.h is just a normal class which is in the default project.

Comment: So you would like to have a `SquareCustom` in project A you could refer to while the implementation would be defined in external projects ? (say, project B). Looks like a perfect job for [protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html). Create a `SquareCustom` protocol in project A, you could refer to an object implementing that protocol and then in every consumer of project A actually implement the protocol in various ways.

Comment: Gonna try that solution.

Comment: Still couldn't try because I'm really busy with another part of the program, but I think your solution should work. Thanks :)